# AdsBot-Google making requests that include the domain name and result in 404

Tags: google-ads

AdsBot-Google bot has recently started making a lot of requests results in 404. These are not likely to ever be requested by users and all include the domain name so instead of requesting `/index.html` it requests `/example.org/index.html` which, of course, leads to 404.

Anyone else who has experienced similar things and have ideas on remedying the situation? For now, I think I'll simply add a block on the `robots.txt` file.

When this started happening, we weren't running AdSense on our website. However, some AdWords campaigns were created (yet not launched) if that helps.

Here are some sample requests. The IPs are from Google:

```
>      IP[66.249.89.119] REQUEST[/colnect.com/en/stamps/list/year/1949/country/2979-Deutschland_DDR]
> REFERER[] AGENT[AdsBot-Google (+http://www.google.com/adsbot.html)] 
>      IP[66.249.89.119] REQUEST[/colnect.com/en/coins/list/page/4/currency/1601-Talar_niemiecki]
> REFERER[] AGENT[AdsBot-Google (+http://www.google.com/adsbot.html)] 
>      IP[66.249.89.121] REQUEST[/colnect.com/en/coins/list/currency/17-z▒_-_Polski_z▒oty/year/1966]
> REFERER[] AGENT[AdsBot-Google (+http://www.google.com/adsbot.html)] 
>      IP[66.249.89.121] REQUEST[/colnect.com/en/coins/list/country/2097-Malta] REFERER[]
> AGENT[AdsBot-Google (+http://www.google.com/adsbot.html)] 
>      IP[66.249.89.119] REQUEST[/colnect.com/en/coins/countries/collection/vargasvict]
> REFERER[] AGENT[AdsBot-Google (+http://www.google.com/adsbot.html)]
>      IP[66.249.89.117] REQUEST[/colnect.com/en/coins/list/series/72659-1824~1830_-_Carlos_X/country/1208-Francia]
> REFERER[] AGENT[AdsBot-Google (+http://www.google.com/adsbot.html)]
>      IP[66.249.89.121] REQUEST[/colnect.com/en/banknotes/series/country/4146-Rusija]
> REFERER[] AGENT[AdsBot-Google (+http://www.google.com/adsbot.html)]
>      IP[66.249.89.117] REQUEST[/colnect.com/en/banknotes/list/variant/1489] REFERER[]
> AGENT[AdsBot-Google (+http://www.google.com/adsbot.html)]
>      IP[66.249.89.121] REQUEST[/colnect.com/en/stamps/years/country/10648-▒е▒м▒д▒кие_▒▒▒▒ова]
> REFERER[] AGENT[AdsBot-Google (+http://www.google.com/adsbot.html)]
>      IP[66.249.89.121] REQUEST[/colnect.com/en/phonecards/phonecard/454762-Zodiac_-Rabbit-KS-JTTLx_-_Zodiac_countrywide_valid-JITONG-中▒]
> REFERER[] AGENT[AdsBot-Google (+http://www.google.com/adsbot.html)]
```

Comment: The fact that your server is returning a 404 response means that your site is working, what is not working is Google's bot. There's little that you can do other than check your DNS is setup correctly, sometimes Google's bot goes wrong and results in this ***non-issue***.  Rarely, your host could go wrong and where you used shared hosting sometimes their settings can temporary go wrong and return someone elses site on your domain, but this doesn't seem the case as those URL's dont see to exist anywhere on the net. Other than clicking 'issue fixed' theres nothing to worry about or do.

Comment: Yes, I know what 404 means :) Question is here to perhaps learn if there's a reason that all these bogus requests started and maybe that reason can be eliminated.

Comment: I think google has a tendency to cache old data forever and at one point during your website updating, `/example.com/index.html` actually existed and since the update, you removed that URL and google thinks you just removed it without notifying them of the new link via a 301 status. I think that's the case. What happens if you attach your domain to webmaster tools and check its crawl errors?

Comment: Well, as I said in my comment, `There's little that you can` and `Other than clicking 'issue fixed' theres nothing to worry about or do` its a common thing, not uncommon that Google sometimes spiders non existant pages, your find many similar questions and answers to this one on the site already.

Comment: Oh my god!! Do not ever click the "fixed" button for a 404 that is correct!! You are telling Google that the page should exist and that you fixed the problem. If the page does not exist for a damn good reason, then there is nothing to fix! You are actually creating an endless loop as many times that you mark anything fixed that should not exist.

Comment: @Mike I assure you that Google forgets rather easily. It does not cache links to follow outside of the fetch queue and that comes from links on pages and links that continue to resolve. Otherwise, if a page does not exist, it is marked as such in the database and never enters the fetch queue again unless **new links** are found. In this case and many others, it is likely a scraper that made a mistake and posted a bunch of links on a site. This looks like a common error that I see often. Some of this software is not at all sophisticated and is used to create bogus/junk sites.

Comment: This conversation isn't related to what I'm asking about really.